# How do I add a newline in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently made a simple game where the user guesses the program's favorite color. Almost everything is fine about the code but I just need to find a way to create a single piece of a newline to make it more readable. **Any help will be appreciated!**

Anyways, here is the code:

```
import random


def color_guess():
    color_sets = {
        'Green': 1,
        'Blue': 2,
        'Red': 3,
        'Yellow': 4,
    }

    user_name = input("Welcome! Please enter your username: ")

    print(user_name + " your goal is to guess my favorite color.")
    print("Your choices are: 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', and 'Yellow'")

    favorite_color = random.choice(list(color_sets))

    guess = input("What do you think? ")

    if guess == favorite_color:
        print("Gg! You guessed my favorite color: " + favorite_color)

    else:
        print("Nope. It was: " + favorite_color)


color_guess()
```

When I add `print("\n")`, It creates 2 newlines instead of one. Is there a way to fix this?

Example:

```
Welcome! Please enter your username:


user_name your goal is to guess my favorite color. 


Your choices are: 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', and 'Yellow'
```

And so on.

But I want it to be this way.

```
Welcome! Please enter your username:

user_name your goal is to guess my favorite color. 

Your choices are: 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', and 'Yellow'
```

Etc.

Comment: `print()` without any arguments will print an empty line (i.e. a single newline). Is that what you want? You can also use `print(..., end="\n\n")` with your existing statements to get an extra newline.

Comment: The other way is to tack the `\n` on the end of the previous message.

Comment: I want a single newline to make it readable (for me at least)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `end` argument to the `print` function to get a different line ending - in this case, you can use it to get two newlines instead of one.

```
print("Gg! You guessed my favorite color: " + favorite_color, end="\n\n")
```

Another option is to use an empty `print` statement, but being explicit about having an extra newline is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Either add the `"\n"` to the end of your existing `print`

```
print(user_name + " your goal is to guess my favorite color.\n")
```

or just use

```
print()
```

for a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Python adds a linebreak after each Print Statement automatically, so if you have a print Statement with ("\n") you have two linebreaks. there are 3 ways to solve this:

1. add the line break to the end of all your print statements

```
print("Hello world\n")
print("Hello world\n")
```

2. remove the automatic linebreak by setting the 'end' parameter to an empty string

```
print("Hello world", end = "")
print("\n")
print("Hello world")
```

3. use an empty string as linebreak, because the print statement sets a linebreak anyway

```
print("Hello world")
print("")
print("Hello world")
```